# Using sed to display character string containing one or more pattern characters in a line and ignore other strings

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I want to pass the result of a **sed command** to a variable to only read part of each line of a file. For example, here is the content of my input file named "fic1.txt":

-->**cat fic1.txt**:

```
/data/test/AAAA1.txt: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
/data/test/AAAA2.txt: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
/data/test/AAAA3.txt: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
/data/test/BBBB1.txt: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1
/data/test/BBBB2.txt: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1
/data/test/BBBB3.txt: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1
/data/test/BBBB4.txt: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1
/data/test/CCCC1.txt: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1
/data/test/CCCC2.txt: text/plain; charset=unknown-8bit
```

So I want to use **sed to pass the result on variable**, such as:

-> **Output_result1:**

```
us-ascii
us-ascii
us-ascii
iso-8859-1
iso-8859-1
iso-8859-1
iso-8859-1
iso-8859-1
unknown-8bit
```

-> **Output_result2:**

```
/data/test/AAAA1.txt
/data/test/AAAA2.txt
/data/test/AAAA3.txt
/data/test/BBBB1.txt
/data/test/BBBB2.txt
/data/test/BBBB3.txt
/data/test/BBBB4.txt
/data/test/CCCC1.txt
/data/test/CCCC2.txt
```

For the first one output, I'm used this following sed command which works:

```
var_type_fic=`cat fic1.txt |sed -r 's/.*charset=([^ ]+).*/\1/'|sort`

for fic in $var_type_fic; do
   echo "$fic"
done
```

But for the second, I can't find the regex match that is going well. Can someone help please?

Comment: Welcome, use the modern `$(...)` for command substitution instead of backticks.

Comment: You can use `printf "%s\n" "${var_type_fic[@]}"` instead of a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is *easiest* done with `cut` as [waltinator shows in their answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/686375/493832), but since you ask about a `sed` solution, here's one of those:

```
#n
# The above turns off the default output, just like using -n on the
# command line would do (#n must be the first two characters of the
# script).

# Save the original line to the hold space.
h

# Remove all up to and including the last equal sign.
# Write the modified text to "Output_result1".
s/.*=//
w Output_result1

# Fetch the original line from the hold space.
g

# Remove all from and including the first colon.
# Write the modified text to "Output_result2".
s/:.*//
w Output_result2
```

Testing it:

```bsh
$ sed -f script file
```

```bsh
$ cat Output_result1
us-ascii
us-ascii
us-ascii
iso-8859-1
iso-8859-1
iso-8859-1
iso-8859-1
iso-8859-1
unknown-8bit
```

```bsh
$ cat Output_result2
/data/test/AAAA1.txt
/data/test/AAAA2.txt
/data/test/AAAA3.txt
/data/test/BBBB1.txt
/data/test/BBBB2.txt
/data/test/BBBB3.txt
/data/test/BBBB4.txt
/data/test/CCCC1.txt
/data/test/CCCC2.txt
```

Without using a separate script:

```bsh
sed -n  -e h -e 's/.*=//' -e 'w Output_result1' \
        -e g -e 's/:.*//' -e 'w Output_result2' file
```

---

Depending on how you're actually planning to *use* this data, you may possibly want to read the data into shell variables directly.  If you use `:` and `=` as delimiters, you can do that in a simple loop:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

while IFS=':=' read -r pathname junk charset
do
        printf 'pathname="%s"\tcharset="%s"\n' "$pathname" "$charset"
done <file
```

For the given data, this would output

```
pathname="/data/test/AAAA1.txt" charset="us-ascii"
pathname="/data/test/AAAA2.txt" charset="us-ascii"
pathname="/data/test/AAAA3.txt" charset="us-ascii"
pathname="/data/test/BBBB1.txt" charset="iso-8859-1"
pathname="/data/test/BBBB2.txt" charset="iso-8859-1"
pathname="/data/test/BBBB3.txt" charset="iso-8859-1"
pathname="/data/test/BBBB4.txt" charset="iso-8859-1"
pathname="/data/test/CCCC1.txt" charset="iso-8859-1"
pathname="/data/test/CCCC2.txt" charset="unknown-8bit"
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong tool. Read `man cut`,

```
cut -d= -f2 fic1.txt
cut '-d:'  -f1 fic1.txt
```

It's easy.